# Why does this C++ program not use 100% CPU but only 10%

Tags: c++, performance, cpu

This program isn't using all the cpu power.
I was expecting it to take over the cpu and run the code the fastest possible, but it only use 10 max

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long x = 600851475143;
    unsigned long long i = x-1;

    while(i <= x) {
            cout << "\r";
            cout << i;

            if((x % i) == 0) {
                    cout << "\n\n";
                    cout << i;

                    break;
            }

            i--;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

it only goes to a max of 10%

Comment: Because it only maxes out one of the cores.

Comment: Due to the simplicity of your program, it only needs 10% of the CPU to run...

Comment: It's because of your `cout`s.

Comment: i thought of it, but i goes on for a veeery long time, shouldn't it be using more cpu and complete it in less time?

Comment: Maybe if you have your program calculate every prime number between 1 and 100,000,000,000,000. Throw some BigInts in there for fun.

Comment: i tryed ever without the couts but it's the same

Comment: I ran this and it used about 90% of a core.  Are you sure the problem isn't with your measurement?

Comment: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/7480/immagineci.png

Comment: I'm fluent in neither italian nor windows, but I think you have 8 cores and an overall utilization of 13%.  13*8=104.  So I think you're maxxing out one core.

Comment: oh.. i suppose you're right... but isn't there a way to use all cores?

Comment: Making a program use all cores is a fundamentally hard problem.  It's called multithreading (or parallel programming, or multiprocessing, etc.).  There are books about it.  The short version is that you need to divide the work into pieces, create threads, and give each thread a piece of the work.

Comment: Have you also considered that Branch prediction is at work in your code?

Answer (score 10):

The speed is probably limited by the speed of the output device. If you pipe the output to a file on disk, it'll be limited by the disk speed. If you just write to a console, it'll be limited by the speed of the console. Either way, the CPU will rarely be the limit.

Edit: since some people apparently don't quite understand the code, perhaps it's best to simplify it a bit. Let's simplify the loop by leaving out the `if` statement, leaving just:

```
unsigned long long x = 600851475143;
unsigned long long i = x-1;

while(i <= x) {
        cout << "\r";
        cout << i;
        i--;
}
```

So, what this does is start from `600851475143`, count down to 0, then stop when `i` wraps around to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` (typically 2<sup>64</sup>-1).

Now, if we add the `if` statement back in, we can mostly ignore the *body* that it controls, but we do also get a remainder operation happening every iteration. Without that, the CPU usage would almost certainly be substantially lower still (though the exact number is likely to depend heavily on the hardware -- e.g., if you write the output to a disk, the disk's sustained bandwidth will be the controlling factor).

Comment: Often that's the case, but this program hardly outputs anything at all.

Comment: @dspeyer: That doesn't change the fact that essentially *all* it does is write output.

Comment: Essentially all it does is arithmetic and decide *not* to write output.

Comment: @dspeyer I suspect the amount of output is not relevant - it's the overhead of having to write to cout every loops v.s the extremely minimal work the CPU has to do (a couple of conditionals, and a counter decrement).

Comment: @dspeyer I don't see it deciding not to write output - it outputs i on every iteration.

Comment: @dspeyer: See edit. It looks to me like you've misunderstood the code. In fact, if you had enough time for it to run to completion, the total output should come to something like 3.5 petabytes.

Comment: I actually ran it and it didn't print anything for about 20 seconds (then I got bored and killed it).  When you send text to cout with no \n character, cout doesn't actually output it.  It just buffers it.  Change that early cout<<'\r' to cout<<'\n' and it will output plenty and the cpu usage will drop to almost zero.

Comment: @dspeyer: Eventually, its buffer will fill, and the data will be written out. I suppose it's possible you simply have so much better of a computer than I do that you have a spare 3.5 petabytes of RAM that cout is using as its output buffer. I hope you'll forgive me if I find that somewhat doubtful.

Comment: Eventually, yes.  If you have the patience to run the program that long.  In practice, the program maxes out one cpu without outputing anything until the user gets bored and kills it.

Comment: @dspeyer: Obviously not, or the OP wouldn't have asked the question he did. Just for one possibility, standard output doesn't have to be line buffered -- it can be unbuffered, in which case your notion of how it will work is 100% false from beginning to end.

Comment: @dspeyer In addition to Jerry's comments, wouldn't writing to a buffer be a bottleneck in itself? RAM is slow compared to registers / cache.

Comment: Most profiling tools treat waiting for ram as cpu used.  If a process is stalling on a mov instruction, the os can't swap in another process to use that time.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are making blocking I/O calls via cout.  Remove the cout statements and it will consume more cpu.

Whenever a thread is blocked on an I/O operation to complete, including stdout which waits for the console to print, the thread is an blocked state. Hence, no CPU time on that thread until the blocking operation is complete. stdout, the kernel, and the console all provide a little bit of buffering to prevent an I/O block, but eventually a program writing fast enough will exceed the buffering provided.

Note. On Windows, this program (with the cout print statements removed) will only use as a maximum of one core of CPU. If you are on a quad core, it will only consume 25% of CPU as reported on Windows task manager.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps the downvoter wanted a bit more explanation of why I/O calls equates to less CPU usage. It's probably obvious to most people, but perhaps not to the OP.

Comment: I downvoted.  See the discussion on the other (roughly equivalent) answer.  When you actually run the program, those cout calls don't block -- they just fill up a buffer inside the process.

Comment: @dspeyer The effect on performance of buffering would seem to me to be hardware dependent, and it's conceivable that more time could be spent on cout (whether buffering or actually outputting) than performing arithmetic.

Comment: I answered this question based on real experience of writing my own code to force cpu usage. While all I/O operations are afforded some buffering by the kernel and the C-Runtime, if you write faster than the console can display, you will **block** writing to stdout. Hence, blocking I/O calls implicitly put the thread out of the Running state and into a Blocked state.  The CPU won't spend cycles on a blocked thread. Hence, the program will consume more CPU when it doesn't have to make any I/O calls.